# asp.net core exclude files from the build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add Protractor to my asp.net-core application.

I added it via npm and it installs the selenium-webdriver which contains a file `Page.aspx.cs`. This is causing a build error but my project doesn't even need to compile it.

So I'm trying to exclude node_modules using project.json

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "compile": {
    "excludeFiles": "node_modules"
  }
},
```

Gives `Illegal characters in path` as does:

```
 "excludeFiles": ["node_modules"]
```

This seems to be related to the _ character but I can't work out why that would be an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get this working using `exclude` instead of `excludeFiles`

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "compile": {
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try with specific file names instead of folder names?

```
"excludeFiles": ["node_modules/path/to/Page.aspx.cs"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** - In the **Solution Explorer**, **right click** on the **node_modules** folder and click **"Exclude From Project"**

**Reason** - If you are working on a client side app that includes npm and node_module folders with large amount of dependencies while using website project in Visual Studio, which is a terrible solution.It results in very slow load times and/or file load errors.

If you have a node_modules folder in your project it will affect the files in the project as well as for publishing. Finally, using a node_modules massive folder in your project there is no way to limit files or folders and end up giving errors.