# VS2015 typescript build error in .net core

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core

When I try to build my solution I receive thousands of messages in the output window in the form    `D:\VisualJobs\VisualJobs\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserverlibrary.d.ts(11545,40): error TS1005: Build:'=' expected.`

in my tsconfig.json file in my exclude section I have:

```
"VisualJobs/VisualJobs/node_modules/*"
```

I have also ensured I have the latest release of typescript installed from the package manager console `npm install typescript -g`

The project is running fine on one machine. I copied the solution files over to another machine and it's on this machine that it errors. I'm guessing it's an environment issue, but I dont know why. VS2015 is being used on both machines, both have all updates installed and both have same extensions etc as well.

Comment: Did you try with `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` ?

Comment: @NicoD no but I did try just     `node_modules/* `

Comment: @bilpor did you put the `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` in the project.json ?

Comment: @FabricioKoch No it's in the tsconfig.json fie where should it go if I need to place it in the project.json file

Comment: @bilpor check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929208/asp-net-core-exclude-files-from-the-build). There's an example there showing how to exclude the node_modules folder for building your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net core exclude files from the build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929208/asp-net-core-exclude-files-from-the-build)

Comment: @FabricioKoch Your links point to excluding in project.json. My code is in tsconfig.json file and it's almost like it's being ignored. I have the project running on a different machine and it's fine there. So it must be an environment issue.

Comment: Since you say it’s working on a different machine: Check your node version, your npm version and your typescript version.